# Count the number of series that satisfy two conditions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I tried to solve the following question but I'm not sure whether it's correct.

Count the number of series $a_{1}, a_{2}\cdots , a_{2013}$ that satisfy the following:

for every $i$ : $a_{i} \in \left\{ -1,1\right\}$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{2013}a_{i} = 5$.

My solution:
I tried to address this question like a problem of arrangement of different marbles of two colors in a row.

White marbles - valued by 1

Black marbles - valued by -1

So I tried to arrange 1009 white marbles and 1004 black marbles: $\binom{2013}{1004}$

Comment: I agree with your answer